how to query based on start and end period dates with MS ACCESS in VB.NET
I'M trying to query based on start and end period dates with MS ACCESS in VB.NET
Table ABSEN can union with table HELPERABSEN
so I want to take the start date and end date from the table PERIOD with where condition based on PERIODNAME from table PERIOD.
if the start date and end date of the data do not exist in the Absen table in the DATEABSEN field then the query creates a new record according to ID2 and INOUT
I don't want to use functions in MS Access because I use SQL for VB.NET.
if there is any other method please guide me
Thanks
Public Class Form1
    Private AbsenService As New ABSENservice()
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.DataSource = AbsenService.GetAbsenfull()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class ABSENservice
    Public Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String
        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\trialabsen.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function
    Private ReadOnly _conn As OleDbConnection
    Private _connectionString As String = GetOledbConnectionString()
    Public Sub New()
        _conn = New OleDbConnection(_connectionString)
    End Sub
    Public Function GetAbsenfull() As IEnumerable(Of ABSEN)
        Dim sql = $"SELECT ABSEN.ID2 AS [ID2],MASTERID2.NAMEID2 AS [NAMEID2],ABSEN.INOUT AS [INOUT],ABSEN.DATEABSEN AS [DATEABSEN],Format(ABSEN.TIME,'hh:mm:ss') AS [TIME],ABSEN.STATUS AS [STATUS] FROM ABSEN INNER JOIN MASTERID2 ON ABSEN.ID2 = MASTERID2.ID2"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of ABSEN)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
Public Class ABSEN
    Public Property ID() As Integer
    Public Property ID2() As String
    Public Property NAMEID2() As String
    Public Property INOUT() As String
    Public Property DATEABSEN() As DateTime
    Public Property TIME() As String
    Public Property STATUS() As String

End Class

RESULT FROM CODE



ID2
NAMEID2
INOUT
DATEABSEN
TIME
STATUS




1000
JACK
IN
21-Apr-24
08:00:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
IN
22-May-24
08:00:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
OUT
22-May-24
17:00:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
IN
22-May-24
08:00:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
OUT
22-May-24
17:00:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
OUT
21-Apr-24
17:00:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
IN
21-Apr-24
08:00:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
OUT
21-Apr-24
17:00:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
IN
22-Apr-24
08:00:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
OUT
22-Apr-24
17:00:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
IN
22-Apr-24
08:00:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
OUT
22-Apr-24
17:00:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
IN
24-Apr-24
08:00:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
OUT
24-Apr-24
17:00:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
OUT
25-Apr-24
17:00:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
IN
25-Apr-24
08:00:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
IN
20-May-24
08:00:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
OUT
20-May-24
17:00:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
IN
20-May-24
08:00:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
OUT
20-May-24
17:00:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
IN
21-May-24
08:00:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
OUT
21-May-24
17:00:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
IN
21-May-24
08:00:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
OUT
21-May-24
17:00:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
IN
20-Apr-24
08:00:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
OUT
20-Apr-24
17:00:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
IN
20-Apr-24
08:00:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
OUT
20-Apr-24
17:00:00
PRESENT



Sample Data
Table ABSEN



ID2
INOUT
DATEABSEN
TIME
STATUS




1000
IN
20-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1000
OUT
20-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT


1002
IN
20-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1002
OUT
20-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT


1000
IN
21-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1000
OUT
21-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT


1002
IN
21-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1002
OUT
21-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT


1000
IN
22-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1000
OUT
22-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT


1002
IN
22-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1002
OUT
22-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT


1000
IN
24-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1002
OUT
24-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT


1000
OUT
24-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT


1002
IN
24-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1000
IN
20-May-24
08:00
PRESENT


1000
OUT
20-May-24
17:00
PRESENT


1002
IN
20-May-24
08:00
PRESENT


1002
OUT
20-May-24
17:00
PRESENT


1000
IN
21-May-24
08:00
PRESENT


1000
OUT
21-May-24
17:00
PRESENT


1002
IN
21-May-24
08:00
PRESENT


1002
OUT
21-May-24
17:00
PRESENT


1000
IN
22-May-24
08:00
PRESENT


1000
OUT
22-May-24
17:00
PRESENT


1002
IN
22-May-24
08:00
PRESENT


1002
OUT
22-May-24
17:00
PRESENT



Table HELPERABSEN



ID2
INOUT
DATEABSEN
TIME
STATUS




1000
IN
23-Apr-24

NOT PRESENT


1000
OUT
23-Apr-24

NOT PRESENT


1002
IN
23-Apr-24

NOT PRESENT


1002
OUT
23-Apr-24

NOT PRESENT


1000
OUT
24-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT


1002
IN
24-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1000
IN
24-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1002
OUT
24-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT



Table MASTERID2



ID2
NAMEID2
POSITION




1000
JACK
STAFF


1001
ROY
OPERATOR


1002
KEN
STAFF


1003
REY
OPERATOR



Table PERIOD



PERIODNAME
STARTDATE
ENDDATE




FIRST
22-Apr-24
25-Apr-24


SECOND
22-May-24
25-May-24



DESIRED RESULT ALL
but I want to base it on each period



ID2
NAMEID2
INOUT
DATEABSEN
TIME
STATUS




1000
JACK
IN
22-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
OUT
22-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
IN
22-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
OUT
22-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
IN
23-Apr-24

NOT PRESENT


1000
JACK
OUT
23-Apr-24

NOT PRESENT


1002
KEN
IN
23-Apr-24

NOT PRESENT


1002
KEN
OUT
23-Apr-24

NOT PRESENT


1000
JACK
IN
24-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
OUT
24-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
IN
24-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
OUT
24-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
IN
25-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
OUT
25-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
IN
25-Apr-24
08:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
OUT
25-Apr-24
17:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
IN
22-May-24
08:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
OUT
22-May-24
17:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
IN
22-May-24
08:00
PRESENT


1002
KEN
OUT
22-May-24
17:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
IN
23-May-24
08:00
PRESENT


1000
JACK
OUT
23-May-24




1002
KEN
IN
23-May-24




1002
KEN
OUT
23-May-24




1000
JACK
IN
24-May-24




1000
JACK
OUT
24-May-24




1002
KEN
IN
24-May-24




1002
KEN
OUT
24-May-24




1000
JACK
IN
25-May-24




1000
JACK
OUT
25-May-24




1002
KEN
IN
25-May-24




1002
KEN
OUT
25-May-24






I think I would build the list by some fancy looping, but you can get close with SQL.
First create a table or a query that will return 10 numbers named TEN:
SELECT DISTINCT [Id] Mod 10 AS Factor
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE MSysObjects.Id > 0

and an INOUT table having one field INOUT and two records:
IN  
OUT

Next, create a UNION query, ALLABSEN:
SELECT 
    ID2, INOUT, DATEABSEN, [TIME], STATUS
FROM 
    ABSEN
UNION 
SELECT 
    ID2, INOUT, DATEABSEN, [TIME], STATUS
FROM 
    HELPERABSEN

and a Cartesian query, ALLDATES, to generate all dates:
SELECT 
    PERIOD.PERIODNAME, [Factor]+[STARTDATE] AS [DATE]
FROM 
    PERIOD, 
    TEN
WHERE 
    [Factor]+[STARTDATE] Between [STARTDATE] And [ENDDATE]
ORDER BY 
    [Factor]+[STARTDATE]

and yet a Cartesian query, ALLID2DATES, to return all possible entries:
SELECT 
    MASTERID2.ID2, MASTERID2.NAMEID2, INOUT.INOUT, ALLDATES.Date
FROM 
    MASTERID2, 
    ALLDATES, 
    INOUT
WHERE
    MASTERID2.POSITION = 'STAFF'
ORDER BY 
    ALLDATES.Date, MASTERID2.ID2, INOUT.INOUT;

Finally, you can assemble the output query, ID2ALLABSEN:
SELECT 
    ALLID2DATES.ID2, ALLID2DATES.NAMEID2, ALLID2DATES.INOUT, ALLID2DATES.DATE, ALLABSEN.TIME, ALLABSEN.STATUS
FROM 
    ALLID2DATES 
LEFT JOIN 
    ALLABSEN 
    ON (ALLID2DATES.DATE = ALLABSEN.DATEABSEN) AND (ALLID2DATES.INOUT = ALLABSEN.INOUT) AND (ALLID2DATES.ID2 = ALLABSEN.ID2)
ORDER BY 
    ALLID2DATES.DATE, ALLID2DATES.ID2, ALLID2DATES.INOUT, [DATE]+[ALLABSEN].[TIME]

Output:


your answer is perfect. sorry I'm late to reply.
where should I put the condition where from table MASTERID2 for field POSITION for only condition STAFF .
Is it possible to be one query?

That I would do in query ALLID2DATES - see edit, please. You could probably assemble it all as one query having a bunch of subqueries, but it wouldn't be nice.

Dim sql = $"SELECT      ALLID2DATES.ID2 AS [ID2], ALLID2DATES.NAMEID2 AS [NAMEID2] , ALLID2DATES.INOUT AS [INOUT], ALLID2DATES.DATE AS [DATEABSEN], Format(ALLABSEN.TIME,'hh:mm:ss') AS [TIME], ALLABSEN.STATUS AS [STATUS] FROM      ALLID2DATES  LEFT JOIN      ALLABSEN      ON (ALLID2DATES.DATE = ALLABSEN.DATEABSEN) AND (ALLID2DATES.INOUT = ALLABSEN.INOUT) AND (ALLID2DATES.ID2 = ALLABSEN.ID2) ORDER BY      ALLID2DATES.DATE, ALLID2DATES.ID2, ALLID2DATES.INOUT, [DATE]+[ALLABSEN].[TIME]"

I have error Additional information: Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysObjects'.

Then you can replace ´TEN´ with a tiny table having just one field and ten records - similar to the INOUT table.

I want to ask what does 10 numbers mean in the TEN table

It works as a "multiplier" in the query which is a Cartesian query. This way you can generate a list of all possible dates for all ID2s, here filtered to be within the range between STARTDATE and ENDDATE.

Did you try altering values of GetStockSearching function in the ABSENservice class that includes a startDate and endDate paramater?
something like this :
Public Function GetStockSearching(startDate As Date, endDate As Date) As IEnumerable(Of ABSEN)
    Dim sql = $"SELECT ABSEN.ID2 AS [ID2], MASTERID2.NAMEID2 AS [NAMEID2], ABSEN.INOUT AS [INOUT], ABSEN.DATEABSEN AS [DATEABSEN], Format(ABSEN.TIME,'hh:mm:ss') AS [TIME], ABSEN.STATUS AS [STATUS] " &
              $"FROM ABSEN INNER JOIN MASTERID2 ON ABSEN.ID2 = MASTERID2.ID2 " &
              $"WHERE ABSEN.DATEABSEN BETWEEN #{startDate:yyyy-MM-dd}# AND #{endDate:yyyy-MM-dd}#"

    Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
        Return _conn.Query(Of ABSEN)(sql).ToList()
    End Using
End Function

Try adding two params startDate and endDate, which are both of type Date, they will be used to filter the ABSEN tables DATEABSEN column using the BETWEEN operator in SQL query.
To use this updated func, call it from Form1_Load event handler and pass in the desired start and end date as arguments.

thanks for your answer but  I want Table ABSEN can union with table HELPERABSEN and I want to take the start date and end date from the table PERIOD with where condition based on PERIODNAME from table PERIOD.

,if the start date and end date of the data do not exist in the Absen table in the DATEABSEN field then the query creates a new record according to ID2 and INOUT
